# Where to put pretty urls configuration

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager

Where should I put this code:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => [
        // your rules go here
    ],
    // ...
],
```

And what rules should I put there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it inside application config.

Its location varies depending on template you are using (basic / advanced).

There is `components` section, where each framework component configured:

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'rules' => [
                // your rules go here
            ],
            // ...
        ],
    ],
];
```

This will prevent passing route passed as `$_GET` parameter `r`.

Note that for pretty urls you also need to add this:

```
`showScriptName` => false,
```

This will prevent showing `index.php` in urls.

As for rules - it's more extensive question. Its content depends on your needs.
You can configure route / group of routes / all routes.

Read more in official docs:

- [UrlManager $enablePrettyUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$enablePrettyUrl-detail)
- [UrlManager $showScriptName](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$showScriptName-detail)
- [UrlManager $rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$rules-detail)
- [Using Pretty Urls](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#using-pretty-urls)
- [Url Rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules)

Comment: I'm using advanced template =>frontend/config/main.php ?

Comment: Depending on your needs, it can be `main.php` or `main-local.php` in one of these folders: `backend`, `common`, `frontend`.

Comment: is there no difference if I put it on main.php ?

Comment: You can read [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-advanced-app.html#configuration-and-environments) to understand more about configuration.

Comment: There is difference, `main-local.php` files have higher priority over `main.php` and used for `dev` mode, `common` folder has higher priority over `backend` / `frontend`.

Comment: so main-local.php and common folder is best option to put the Urlmanager settings. ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76294/discussion-between-arogachev-and-ashton).